# Resorting and removing number gaps using javascript array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to resort and then remove any gaps in the numbers for the `sortOrder` property in this JavaScript array.

**So for example:**

```
p[0].sortOrder = 2; 
p[1].sortOrder = 12;
p[2].sortOrder = 4;
p[3].sortOrder = 8;
p[4].sortOrder = 6; 
p[5].sortOrder = 2; 
p[6].sortOrder = 8;
```

**Should be output to:**

```
p[0].sortOrder = 1; //used to be 2
p[1].sortOrder = 5; //used to be 12
p[2].sortOrder = 2; //used to be 4
p[3].sortOrder = 4; //used to be 8
p[4].sortOrder = 3; //used to be 6 
p[5].sortOrder = 1; //used to be 2
p[6].sortOrder = 4; //used to be 8
```

Here's the function it should run in. I can't wrap my head around the elimination of the gaps in the numbers.

```
function restackSortOrder(p) {

    //Remove any gaps in numbers here while still retaining any duplicate numbers (which should stay grouped together).

    return p;
}
```

Comment: What does the gap mean here ?

Comment: There's a sort order and I can't have the numbers skipping numbers in the sortOrder property.  So if I have two objects in the array: p[0].sortOrder=1 and p[1].sortOrder=3, it needs to convert the 3 to a 2 so there's no number gaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution, with explanation in the comments:

```js
function resortStackorder(p) {
  var match = p.map(function(e) {                   //create array of sortOrder values
                return e.sortOrder;
              })
               .sort(function(a, b) {return a - b}) //sort the array numerically
               .filter(function(e, idx, array) {    //filter out duplicates
                 return e !== array[idx - 1];
               });

  p.forEach(function(e) {  //look up sortOrder's position in the match array
    e.sortOrder = match.indexOf(e.sortOrder) + 1;
  });
} //resortStackorder

var p = [
  {sortOrder: 2},
  {sortOrder: 12},
  {sortOrder: 4},
  {sortOrder: 8},
  {sortOrder: 6},
  {sortOrder: 2},
  {sortOrder: 8}
];

resortStackorder(p);

console.log(JSON.stringify(p));
```

Answer (score 2):

An ES6 version which first uses a `Set` to get the unique items and then a `Map` to map the original values with the indices of the set:

```js
let p = [{sortOrder: 2},{sortOrder: 12},{sortOrder: 4},{sortOrder: 8},{sortOrder: 6},{sortOrder: 2},{sortOrder: 8}];

let map = new Map([...new Set(p.map(o=>o.sortOrder))].sort((a,b)=>a-b).map((sO,ind)=>[sO,ind+1]));
for(let o of p)
 o.sortOrder = map.get(o.sortOrder);

console.log(JSON.stringify(p));
```